# Count words in cell, don't count HTML tags

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have HTML code in an Excel cell.

How to count all words which aren't between `<` and `>`

Alternatively, how can I count all words between `>` and `<`

I want to get a number of words, which aren't HTML tags, classes, attributes etc. I Have i.e. in A1 code like:

```
<div class="x" style="padding:0px;">Lorem <strong>ipsum</strong> <i>bla</i> <a href="#" title="xmix" target="_blank">opana</a> test <span>word</span> bla</div>
```

After calculation in B1 i want to get 7, as a number of clean words `Lorem ipsum bla opana test word bla`

Comment: Please provide an example, including what you expect the output to be

Comment: Can you give more information? What do you want to get in return? Number of characters between HTML tags? Number of different words between the tags? ....

Comment: I can't see a way of doing this without VBA or a lot of helper cells

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stripping HTML From A String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12804067/stripping-html-from-a-string)

Comment: If you can fill out the question a bit, I might have a go at a formula solution.

Comment: @CallumDA added an example and info

Comment: How can you do it? Either with a VBA function which loops through, or a load of helper cells that split on < and >. Have you tried anything like this, or do you just want someone to write the code for you?

Comment: @DavidGlickman well, i have an addon for Excel, which gives a possibility to work with regular expressions to manipulate data in cells. With regular expressions this task is a nobrainer for me - i do pretty all my daily tasks in Excel with regex. But now i'm preparing a workshop, and not all participants will have this addon, thought it is free:) Thats why i need to adopt this task so, that it is accomplished with `pure` Excel instruments

Comment: @TomSharpe yes, i've described the task a bit more - hope it helps

Comment: I do have a formula solution that just needs a bit more tweaking before I publish it. Interesting to compare the complexity of this (pretty long) with regex.

Answer (score 0):

Well I like a challenge so this is a formula solution to the problem. This version only accepts <, > and space as delimiters: it would not be too difficult having got this far to deal with commas, full stops etc.

The algorithm is

```
If current character is <, extract all characters up to next >
If current character is " ", extract all characters up to next non-space
If current character is any other character, extract all characters up to next space or <.

Then count number of strings starting with an alpha character.
```

The formula is

```
=IF(LEFT(MID($A$1,SUMPRODUCT(LEN($C$1:C1))+1,LEN($A$1)),1)="<",
MID(MID($A$1,SUMPRODUCT(LEN($C$1:C1))+1,LEN($A$1)),1,FIND(">",MID($A$1,SUMPRODUCT(LEN($C$1:C1))+1,LEN($A$1))&">")),
IF(LEFT(MID($A$1,SUMPRODUCT(LEN($C$1:C1))+1,LEN($A$1)),1)=" ",
MID(MID($A$1,SUMPRODUCT(LEN($C$1:C1))+1,LEN($A$1)),1,FIND(LEFT(TRIM(MID($A$1,SUMPRODUCT(LEN($C$1:C1))+1,LEN($A$1)))),MID($A$1,SUMPRODUCT(LEN($C$1:C1))+2
```

,LEN($A$1)))),
    MID(MID($A$1,SUMPRODUCT(LEN($C$1:C1))+1,LEN($A$1)),1,AGGREGATE(15,6,SEARCH({" ","<"},MID($A$1,SUMPRODUCT(LEN($C$1:C1))+2,LEN($A$1))&" "),1))))

and to get the counts just

```
=COUNTIF(C2:C100,">=a")
```

The second helper column (column D) is not necessary but is included as a check.

[image]