# Remove HTML tags from string in Excel VBA

Tags: string, vba, excel, tags

I want to remove all HTML tags from a string in Excel VBA.

For example:

```
before_text = "text1 <br> text2 <a href = 'www.data.com' id = 'data'>text3</a> text4"

after_text = RemoveTags(before_text)
```

Result:

```
after_text = "text1  text2 text3 text4"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stripping HTML From A String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12804067/stripping-html-from-a-string)

Answer (score 4):

```
vbscript.regexp
```

Code:

```
Function RemoveHTML(text As String) As String
    Dim regexObject As Object
    Set regexObject = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

    With regexObject
        .Pattern = "<!*[^<>]*>"    'html tags and comments
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .MultiLine = True
    End With

    RemoveHTML = regexObject.Replace(text, "")
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on @zhihar's reply, to make this strip all HTML from the selected cell you can iterate through the selection.

```
Function RemoveHTML(text As String) As String
    Dim regexObject As Object
    Set regexObject = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

    With regexObject
        .Pattern = "<!*[^<>]*>"    'html tags and comments
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .MultiLine = True
    End With

    RemoveHTML = regexObject.Replace(text, "")
End Function


Sub StripHtmlSelected()
    For Each Cell In Selection
        If Not Cell.HasFormula Then
            Cell.Value = RemoveHTML(Cell.Value)
        End If
    Next Cell
End Sub
```