# Is there an Excel formula to display this text in a clean, readable manner by removing all HTML?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have some text that is using HTML, but for reporting purposes I'd like to pull this into a cell using a formula whilst removing the HTML and replacing 
 with a " ". For example:

`Keep this<br><span style='color:#F4762D'>TEXT</span>`

Would become

`Keep this TEXT`

I've tried using nested SUBSTITUTE functions but I just can't get it to work. Does anybody have a solution?

This is the formula I tried (which worked for another spreadsheet, but because the HTML functions were in different places it doesn't work for this one):

`IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(L2,MID(LEFT(L2,FIND(">",L2)),FIND("<",L2),LEN(L2)),""),"</span>",""),"<br>"," "),L2)`

Text in other spreadsheet:

`<span style="font-size:150%">Keep this</span><br>TEXT`

I've tried changing the order but can't figure out where cell references need to go.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove HTML tags from string in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47366923/remove-html-tags-from-string-in-excel-vba)

Answer (score 4):

You could try:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",,TAKE(TEXTSPLIT(A1,"<",">"),,1))
```

This would assume no angle brackets other than those that would demarcate html-tags.

Comment: Hi JvdV, thanks for this! This is working in Excel for me. Do you happen to know how this would translate to Google Sheets? The TAKE function doesn't appear to be supported.

Comment: @RyanWatson if you wanted Google sheets, why tag if for Excel?  They are not the same thing

Comment: Agreed with comments above. Make sure you do not get tags mixed up. For GS I'd use `=TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(A1,"<[^<>]*>"," "))`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Your Text is pasted in Cell A3
Formulas for Step 1, Step 2, Step 3 and Last Results cell as below.

```
Step 1 - TEXTBEFORE(A3,"<",1,1,1)
Step 2 - TEXTAFTER(A3,"'>",1,1,,NOT FOUND)
Step 3 - TEXTBEFORE(C3,"<",1,1,1)
Step 4 - CONCAT(B3," ",G3)
```

[image: Actual working as below in pic]