# Extract information from a MURAL board, pull HTML code to find the attributes/location?

Tags: html, excel, vba

I have to pull information from a MURAL board (design thinking tool, which is pretty much an online whiteboard).  I need to pull the following information for the stickies:
https://app.mural.co/t/hanno1/m/hanno1/1488557783266/465baa38d35e95edc969a5ca9e2a8bb8b6f10310

1. Sticky Note Text
2. Sticky Note Attributes (Color, Size, Shape)
3. Sticky Note Location
4. Image links (and locations if possible)

I have created code that is not working. Nothing is being pulled. It pretty much skips straight from opening to quitting the browser.

Also how do I pull the actual HTML code to find the attributes/location?

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
Dim ie As InternetExplorer, arr(), col
Set ie = New InternetExplorer
Set col = New Collection
With ie
    .Visible = True
    .navigate "https://app.mural.co/t/nextgencomms9753/m/nextgencomms9753/1536712668215/cd70107230d7f406058157a3bb8e951cedc9afc0"

    While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

    Dim listedItems As Object, item As Object, prices As Object, price As Object, j As Long
    Set listedItems = .document.getElementsByClassName("widget-layer-inner")
    For Each item In listedItems
        Set prices = item.getElementsByClassName("Linkify")
        ReDim arr(0 To prices.Length - 1)    'you could limit this after by redim to 0 to 0
        j = 0
        For Each price In prices
            arr(j) = price.innerText
            j = j + 1
        Next
        col.Add Array(item.getElementsByClassName("widgets-container") (0).innerText, arr)
    Next
    .Quit

    Dim item2 As Variant, rowNum As Long
    For Each item2 In col
        rowNum = rowNum + 1
        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
            .Cells(rowNum, 1) = Replace$(Trim$(item2(0)), Chr$(10), Chr$(32))
            .Cells(rowNum, 2).Resize(1, UBound(item2(1)) + 1) = item2(1)
        End With
    Next
    End With
End Sub
```

[image: Code info]

Comment: So what is happening instead?

Comment: From the code below, nothing is being pulled.  It pretty much skips straight from opening to quitting the browser

Comment: I’ll post something later. Had a quick skim and seems doable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, I think using IE automation should be avoided where possible, especially if you can figure out a method to emulate this request via a web request.

A little background on this method

---

I'm submitting two web requests. One to get an authorization token, and another to get the the JSON from the page which populate the widgets on screen. I figured this out by studying the web requests sent back and forth between the client (me) and the server, and emulated those requests.The approach outlined below is pretty fast, about 2 seconds without URL decoding, and 10 seconds with decoding.

Things you'll need for this to work

---

1. Explicit Reference set to Microsoft XML v6.0
2. Explicit Reference set to Microsoft Scripting Runtime
3. The VBA-JSON project included into your project, get that [here](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/releases)

**Code**

I split out token and json retrieval into two functions. What you get back from getJSON is a dictionary. This dictionary is somewhat nested, so you refer to items by key to traverse the dictionary down. E.g. `MyDict(property1)(childPropertyOfproperty1)(childPropertyOf...)` etc.

Here's the code.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub SubmitRequest()
    Const URL As String = "https://app.mural.co/t/hanno1/m/hanno1/1488557783266/465baa38d35e95edc969a5ca9e2a8bb8b6f10310"
    Dim returnobject    As Object
    Dim widgets         As Object
    Dim widget          As Variant
    Dim WidgetArray     As Variant
    Dim id              As String
    Dim i               As Long

    Set returnobject = getJSON(URL, getToken(URL))
    Set widgets = returnobject("widgets")
    ReDim WidgetArray(0 To 7, 0 To 10000)

    For Each widget In widgets
        'Only add if a text item, change if you like
        If returnobject("widgets")(widget)("type") = "murally.widget.TextWidget" Then
            WidgetArray(0, i) = URLDecode(returnobject("widgets")(widget)("properties")("text"))
            WidgetArray(1, i) = returnobject("widgets")(widget)("properties")("fontSize")
            WidgetArray(2, i) = returnobject("widgets")(widget)("properties")("backgroundColor")
            WidgetArray(3, i) = returnobject("widgets")(widget)("x")
            WidgetArray(4, i) = returnobject("widgets")(widget)("y")
            WidgetArray(5, i) = returnobject("widgets")(widget)("width")
            WidgetArray(6, i) = returnobject("widgets")(widget)("height")
            WidgetArray(7, i) = returnobject("widgets")(widget)("id")
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next

    ReDim Preserve WidgetArray(0 To 7, i - 1)

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        .Range("A1:H1") = Array("Text", "FontSize", "BackgroundColor", "X Position", "Y Position", "Width", "Height", "ID")
        .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(i+ 1, 8)).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(WidgetArray)
    End With

End Sub

Public Function getJSON(URL As String, Token As String) As Object
    Dim baseURL         As String
    Dim getRequest      As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim URLParts        As Variant
    Dim jsonconvert     As Object
    Dim id              As String
    dim user            as String

    URLParts = Split(URL, "/", , vbBinaryCompare)
    id = URLParts(UBound(URLParts) - 1)
    user = URLParts(UBound(URLParts) - 2)
    baseURL = Replace(Replace("https://app.mural.co/api/murals/{user}/{ID}", "{ID}", id), "{user}", user)

    Set getRequest = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

    With getRequest
        .Open "GET", baseURL
        .setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer " & Token
        .setRequestHeader "Referer", URL
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:64.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/64.0"
        .send
        Set getJSON = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText)
    End With

End Function

Public Function getToken(URL As String) As String
    Dim getRequest      As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim URLParts        As Variant
    Dim position        As Long
    Dim jsonconvert     As Object
    Dim Token           As Object
    Dim State           As String
    Dim User            As String
    Dim json            As String
    Dim referer         As String
    Dim id              As String
    Dim posturl         As String

    json = "{""state"": ""{STATE}""}"
    posturl = "https://app.mural.co/api/v0/visitor/{user}.{ID}"
    referer = "https://app.mural.co/t/{user}/m/{user}/{ID}"
    URLParts = Split(URL, "/", , vbBinaryCompare)
    position = InStrRev(URL, "/")

    URL = Left$(URL, position - 1)
    State = URLParts(UBound(URLParts))
    id = URLParts(UBound(URLParts) - 1)
    User = URLParts(UBound(URLParts) - 2)

    json = Replace(json, "{STATE}", State)
    posturl = Replace(Replace(posturl, "{user}", User), "{ID}", id)
    referer = Replace(Replace(referer, "{user}", User), "{ID}", id)

    Set getRequest = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

    With getRequest
        .Open "POST", posturl
        .setRequestHeader "origin", "https://app.mural.co"
        .setRequestHeader "Referer", referer
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:64.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/64.0"
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8"
        .send json
        Set jsonconvert = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText)
    End With

    getToken = jsonconvert("token")

End Function

' from https://stackoverflow.com/a/12804172/4839827
Public Function URLDecode(ByVal StringToDecode As String) As String
    With CreateObject("htmlfile")
        .Open
        .Write StringToDecode
        .Close
        URLDecode = .body.outerText
    End With
End Function
```

Here's the output returned. There are other properties available, however this code is meant to just give you an idea how to pull this back.

[image: Results]

Comment: Hey, thanks for the code... When I try and run it, I get an error here (object not defined):           Set jsonconvert = jsonconvert.ParseJson(.responseText)

Comment: You mean this line `Set jsonconvert = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText)`? Did you add the VBA-JSON project to your project as I outlined in point 3 under requirements? Basically copy over the whole JsonConverter.bas file into your project and it should work.

Comment: Ahh, I downloaded it, but did not import it into the excel.. This works for me!  Only issue is that when I try and apply this to a similar MURAL link (private information), it's not working.  We were hoping to be able to use this code by switching out the URL to similar boards.  The error that I am receving is the following:          Err.Raise 10001, "JSONConverter", json_ParseErrorMessage(JsonString, json_Index, "Expecting '{' or '['")

Comment: Also I can repost this as a new thread if it would help you get more feedback points, considering this is actually a follow-up question

Comment: Hmm, sounds like the data coming back from the server is not in a JSON format. Could be for several reasons. Not sure, but a new question might be the best course here.

Comment: I think I found an issue that might be preventing this from working. I wasn't updating the user in the `getJSON` function. I've updated the code to do this, let me know if that resolves the issue :)